# Tailwind -- CSS is not recognised in my project

Tags: python, html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

It's my first time using Tailwind CSS. For some reason, the styles I am trying to apply are not being recognised.

1. I ran `npx tailwindcss init`, to generate a tailwind.config.js. This is my file right now:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./templates/*.html'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

2. I created a src/input.css file with the following lines inside:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

3. Then, I ran the command: `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./templates/css/style.css`

With that, a file style.css is generated *[But, I noticed that my Visual Studio Code does not recognizes it as a css file but a plain text file]*

4. Now, this is the code of my templates/base.html file:

```
<!-- base.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
{% include 'header.html' %}

    <main>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </main>

{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

and templates/header.html code:

```
<body> 
  <header class="bg-purple-100 sticky top-0 z-10 flex justify-between items-center px-4 py-2">
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="text-white">HELLO WORLD</a>
    <div class="flex justify-between items-center space-x-4">
        <a href="" class="text-white">Search</a>
        <a href="" class="text-white">Airing</a>
        <a href="" class="text-white">Site theme</a>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="toggleDropdown()" class="dropbtn text-white">Profile</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a>
                <a href="{% url 'settings' %}">Settings</a>
                <a href="{% url 'notifications' %}">Notifications</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</header>
```

5. After running the command: `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./templates/css/style.css --watch`

This is the output I get:

**Rebuilding...

warn - No utility classes were detected in your source files. If this is unexpected, double-check the `content` option in your Tailwind CSS configuration.
warn - [https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration`*](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration%60*)*

My folder structure, if it helps:

```
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── input.css
├── templates
│   ├── app1
│   │   ├── app1_1.html
│   │   ├── app1_2.html
│   │   └── app1_3.html
│   ├── css
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── app2
│   │   └── app2_1.html
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── header.html
│   ├── footer.html
├── tailwind.config.js
```

How do I need to configure my Tailwind CSS config file correctly? Or is there another issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Tailwind is not going deep enough to find the templates you are creating. Add another line to the content section something like

```
content: ['./templates/**/*.html'],
```

Should be able to find the template files then and generate the classes.